# Raise fastapi HTTPException not showing full stacktrace to console

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I would like to get full stacktrace of exceptions in my log when raising HTTPException, For now I only receive `GET /info HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request`. What Client receives is ok: `Bad Request {"detail": "division by zero"}`.  Im not sure if I should handle and raise again this exception somehow in middleware?

```
import uvicorn

from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/info")
def info():
    try:
        x = 1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        # in console:
        # INFO:     127.0.0.1:44212 - "GET /info HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request
        # and to the client:
        # Error: Bad Request {"detail": "division by zero"}
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8000)
```